# How to print Datetime picker in crystal report?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, datetimepicker

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));      
dt.Columns.Add("Class", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("RollNo", typeof(String));
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in dgv_Student.Rows)
{
  dt.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells["Name"].Value, dgr.Cells["Class"].Value, dgr.Cells["RollNo"].Value);
 }
        ds.Tables.Add(dt); 
        CrystalReport1 cr = new CrystalReport1 ();          
        cr.SetDataSource(ds);
```

This is for datagridview to crystal report. I also want to display datimepicker values that are dtpFrom and dtpTo to crystal Report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a *Text Object* somewhere in your Crystal report by *Crystal Reports* -> *Insert* -> *Text Object*.  The default name for the Text Object is *Text1*.  You can see that under the text object properties.  You can change this name if you want.  Now on your C# code you need to pass the values of the Time.

Example:

```
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load the report path
    string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReportTime.rpt");
    rptDoc.Load(reportPath);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc; 
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReportTime.rpt");
        rptDoc.Load(reportPath);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
    }

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));      
    dt.Columns.Add("Class", typeof(String));
    dt.Columns.Add("RollNo", typeof(String));
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in dgv_Student.Rows)
    {
      dt.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells["Name"].Value, dgr.Cells["Class"].Value, dgr.Cells["RollNo"].Value);
    }
    ds.Tables.Add(dt); 
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);

    // Pass the time to the Crystal Reports text object
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject Text1;
    Text1 = rptDoc.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Text1"] as TextObject;
    Text1.Text = "Time from " + String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(dtpFrom)) + " to " + String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(dtpTo));
}

protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose();
    this.CrystalReportViewer1 = null;
    rptDoc.Close();
    rptDoc.Dispose();
    rptDoc = null;
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not working ,Giving error of "unable to cast object of type System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker of type System.IConvertible"

Comment: dtpFrom.value and dtpTo.value ".Value" was missing. Now is it is working. Thanks